# FCM notification not receiving in IOS 10 swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been trying to get firebase push-notification in my ios app for a long time.  I have tried everything on the internet I could find. But sadly no luck.
Any help would be appreciated.

I am sending notification through firebase console. And sometimes when the app is running on foreground the last part

```
extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
    // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices.
    func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("noti recieve remote notification in extesnion")
         print("%@ debug", remoteMessage)
        print("%@", remoteMessage.appData)

    }
```

gets called,  but nothing happens when the app is in background. I have enabled "Push Notification" and Background Modes" in capabilities.

I have tested this only in a ios 10 device.

Here is my code in `AppDelegate.swift`

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseMessaging
import Firebase
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseInstanceID

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FIRApp.configure()


     /*   let notificationType : UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.alert, UIUserNotificationType.badge, UIUserNotificationType.sound]
        let notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings =  UIUserNotificationSettings(types:notificationType,categories:nil)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)*/

     if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            print("if ios 10 ")
            let authOptions : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_,_ in })

            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        } else {
        print("noti not ios 10")
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        // [END register_for_notifications]



        // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                                         selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                                         name: NSNotification.Name.firInstanceIDTokenRefresh,
                                                         object: nil)




             return true    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("noti didRegister notification woth device tocken")
       /* let tokenChars = UnsafePointer<CChar>(deviceToken.bytes)
        var tokenString = ""

        for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
            tokenString += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [tokenChars[i]])
        }*/
      /* var token: String = ""
        for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
            token += String(format: "%02.2hhx", deviceToken[i] as CVarArg)
        }

        FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.prod)

        print("noti tokenString: \(token)")*/
    }
    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    // [START receive_message]
    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        print("noti notification recieved")
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // Print message ID.
       // print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

        print("%@", "noti didReceiveRemoteNotification log")

        // Print full message.
        print("%@", userInfo)
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    // [START refresh_token]
    func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
        print("noti refresh tocken")

        if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
            print("noti InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
        }

        // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
        connectToFcm()
    }
    // [END refresh_token]

    // [START connect_to_fcm]
    func connectToFcm() {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("noti Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
            } else {
                print("noti Connected to FCM.")
            }
        }
    }
    // [END connect_to_fcm]

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        connectToFcm()
    }

    // [START disconnect_from_fcm]
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
        print("noti Disconnected from FCM.")
    }
    // [END disconnect_from_fcm]
}

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresentNotification notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        print("noti userNotificationCenter #ios10") 
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

        // Print full message.
        print("%@", userInfo)
    }
}

extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
    // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices.
    func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("noti recieve remote notification in extesnion")
         print("%@ debug", remoteMessage)
        print("%@", remoteMessage.appData)

    }

}
```

Comment: try to set the priority of a message to `high`

Comment: @TonyMkenu thanks for the help, but i have already tried setting it. its not the issue.

Comment: @MuneefM i am also having the same problem. have you got the solution? if it is, can you help me with this?

Comment: @GaneshKumar i didnt find a solution yet. and i paused working on it hoping this could be a bug in apple or FCM. and will be fixed in recent updates or so. anyway if you find a solution please post it here also. thanks

Comment: Are you using FCM for only remote push notifications? If you're using Firebase for only remote push notifications, remove the `FIRMessagingDelegate` and remove `connectToFcm` method. You won't need it. Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: @MuneefM checkout my answer

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem by adding the code below to the project.

FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Sandbox will be used when you install the app though TestFlight,
and FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Prod when your app goes live on the App Store.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) 
{
    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Sandbox)
    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Prod)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This is working.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?


  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      let authOptions : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions,
        completionHandler: {_,_ in })

      // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
      // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
      FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

    } else {
      let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
        UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
      application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                           name: .firInstanceIDTokenRefresh,
                                           object: nil)
    FIRApp.configure()
    return true
  }

  func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
  }

  func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
    print("Disconnected from FCM.")
  }

  func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
  }

  func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    connectToFcm()
  }

  func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let chars = (deviceToken as NSData).bytes.bindMemory(to: CChar.self, capacity: deviceToken.count)
    var token = ""

    for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
      token += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [chars[i]])
    }

    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.unknown)

    print("Device Token = ", token)
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("Did Fail to Register for Remote Notifications")
    print("\(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                   fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    // Print message ID.
    print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

    // Print full message.
    print("%@", userInfo)
  }

  // [START refresh_token]
  func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
      print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
    }
    // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
    connectToFcm()
  }
  // [END refresh_token]

  func connectToFcm() {
    FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
      if (error != nil) {
        print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
      } else {
        print("Connected to FCM.")
      }
    }
  }

}


@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

  // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                              withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

    // Print full message.
    print("%@", userInfo)
  }

  @available(iOS 10, *)
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("Userinfo \(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")
    //    print("Userinfo \(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")
  }
}

extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
  // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices.
  func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("%@", remoteMessage.appData)
  }
}
```

Comment: After adding all these also i am not able to receive push notification.Can u please guide me

Comment: @UmaMadhavi have you checked your payload?

Comment: Yes i am receiving .When i connect i am getting but when i connect even that method is not called.

Comment: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)" this warning i am getting .

Comment: .Thanks for ur response. I will share . I have one doubt, do i need to change my deployment for getting notifications ,currently i am using 8.0

Comment: if you are using swift 3 you better change the deployment target to 9

Comment: swift 2.3? ok then ios 8.0 is ok

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129773/discussion-between-uma-madhavi-and-ganesh-kumar).

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, all I did to fix the problem, was actually deleting and reinstalling the app. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for asking this question.

It is compulsory to use below statement while you have comment this line in code

```
FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.prod)
```

Uncomment below code...

Hope it will help you...